# How to optimize MySQL query which contains multiple sub query with multiple UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a query that I'm trying to optimize but haven't had much success. I am trying to calculate day wise usage data using below sql query and returns right result but i want to optimize this. Here i am using multiple sub query with multiple union.I have it working but I am trying to optimize so it runs faster.

```
/*  Plan First day usage */

SELECT 
  msisdn,
  plan_id,
  plan_date,    
  plan_start_date, 
  plan_end_date,   
  ROUND(total_usage_mb, 2) AS usage_mb,   
  DATE(plan_start_date) usage_date,
 0 AS starting_balance, ROUND(total_usage_mb, 2) AS closing_balance,   
'start Using' AS usage_status

FROM 
  `usage_info`    
WHERE
   DATE(created) = '2016-02-07'
   AND package_status = 'Plan Using'
   AND DATE(plan_start_date) = '2016-02-06'
   AND ROUND(total_usage_mb, 2)>=0

 UNION

 /* SUBSCRIBER RUNNING PLAN USAGE */

SELECT
   msisdn,
   plan_id,
   plan_date,
   plan_start_date,
   plan_end_date,
   ROUND(mb - bm, 2) AS usage_mb,
   usage_date,bm AS starting_balance, mb AS closing_balance,
  'Continuous Using' AS usage_status
FROM
(
  SELECT
   a.msisdn,
   a.plan_id,
   a.plan_date,
   a.plan_start_date,
   a.plan_end_date,
   a.mb mb,
   b.bm bm,a.name_source,
   b.created AS usage_date
  FROM
   (
    SELECT
     msisdn,
     plan_id,
     plan_date,
     plan_start_date,
     plan_end_date,
     total_usage_mb AS mb,
     name_source,
     created
    FROM
     `usage_info`
    WHERE
     DATE(created) = '2016-02-07'
    AND package_status = 'Plan Using'
   ) a,
   (
    SELECT
     msisdn,
     plan_id,
     plan_date,
     plan_start_date,
     plan_end_date,
     total_usage_mb bm,
     name_source,
     created
    FROM
     `usage_info`
    WHERE
     DATE(created) = '2016-02-06'
    AND package_status = 'Plan Using'
   ) b
  WHERE
   a.msisdn = b.msisdn
  AND a.plan_id = b.plan_id
  AND a.plan_date=b.plan_date
  AND a.plan_start_date=b.plan_start_date
  AND a.plan_end_date=b.plan_end_date
  AND a.name_source=b.name_source
  AND a.mb>=b.bm
 ) c WHERE  ROUND(mb - bm, 2)>=0

 UNION

 /* SUBSCRIBER PLAN LAST DAY USAGE */

SELECT
msisdn,
plan_id,
plan_date,
plan_start_date,
plan_end_date,
ROUND(mb - bm, 2) AS usage_mb,
  usage_date,bm AS starting_balance, mb AS closing_balance,
'End Using' AS usage_status
FROM
(  
  SELECT 
   a.msisdn,
   a.plan_id,
   a.plan_date,
   a.plan_start_date,   
   a.plan_end_date, 
   a.mb mb,
   b.bm bm,a.name_source,
   b.created AS usage_date 
 FROM
   (
    SELECT
     msisdn,
     plan_id,
     plan_date,
     plan_start_date,
     plan_end_date,
     total_usage_mb AS mb,
     name_source,
     created
    FROM
     `usage_info`
    WHERE
     DATE(created) = '2016-02-07'
    AND package_status = 'Plan Used'
   ) a,
   (
    SELECT
     msisdn,
     plan_id,
     plan_date,
     plan_start_date,
     plan_end_date,
     total_usage_mb bm,
     name_source,
     created
    FROM
     `usage_info`
    WHERE
     DATE(created) = '2016-02-06'
    AND package_status = 'Plan Using'
    ) b
  WHERE
   a.msisdn = b.msisdn
  AND a.plan_id = b.plan_id
  AND a.plan_date=b.plan_date
  AND a.plan_start_date=b.plan_start_date
  AND a.plan_end_date=b.plan_end_date
  AND a.name_source=b.name_source
AND a.mb>=b.bm
 ) c WHERE  ROUND(mb - bm, 2)>=0
```

**Database table schema and some test data found below link**

http://faisal-ibrahim.info/usage_info.sql

Any help on this is appreciated. I'm not too expert with SQL so I am not too well versed in optimizing queries such as these.

Comment: do you have some test data und the table create, id the date range always 2 days '2016-02-07' '2016-02-06' ?

Comment: Here you have database schema and some table data.    http://faisal-ibrahim.info/usage_info.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.

But avoid `FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`

Change `DATE(x) = '2016-02-06'` to

```
    x >= '2016-02-06'
AND x <  '2016-02-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Add `INDEX(msisdn, package_status, created)` and `INDEX(package_status, created)`.

It *may* be worth it to do

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE z 
    SELECT ... GROUP BY DATE(created);
```